# Is it possible to get a date object out of milliseconds in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I know that a sample date object in javascript is constructed from a string containing the year, month and day. I am building a function that takes a date and number of days as arguments and adds the days to the date and returns a new date object from the same.
The approach i used is this:

**a)** Get the milliseconds from the date object

**b)** Convert the days to milliseconds

**c)** Add the two and then derive a date object from the resultant sum.
I need a way to get back to the date from the milliseconds. Thank You for your help

```
function AddDays(x,y){
    //convert the days to milliseconds
    let days_milli=y*24*60*60*1000;
    //get the time in millis from the date
    let days_millis=x.getTime();
    //add the times
    let total=days_milli+days_millis;
    //construct a date object from that
     //this line needs some help
    let date=getDate(total);
    return date;
}
```

Comment: Adding days as multiples of 8.64e7 milliseconds is not a good approach. It doesn't work well where daylight saving is observed as days aren't always 24 hours long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Date class constructor has overloads to support construction of objects from a string and milliseconds. All i needed to do was to invoke new Date and then put the milliseconds in the parameter part.

```
function AddDays(x,y){
    //convert the days to milliseconds
    let days_milli=y*24*60*60*1000;
    //get the time in millis from the datw
    let days_millis=x.getTime();
    //add the times
    let total=days_milli+days_millis;
    //construct a date object from that
    let date=new Date(total);
    return date;
}
```